# An example of a set that is not inaccessible

Tags: set-theory

In Stillwell's "Real Numbers," a set $Z$ is said to be inaccessible if it satisfies the following three conditions:

1) $Z$ has infinite members

2) $X\in Z$ implies the power set $P(X)\in Z$

3) $X\in Z$ implies the range of any function with domain $X$ and values in $Z$ is a member of $Z$.

I would appreciate help with Ex. 3.8.6 which asks for an example of a set that satisfies the first two conditions, but not the third.

Also, in that context, how can I show that $V_{\omega}$ does satisfy the third condition.

($V_{\omega}$ is defined to be the union of all the $V_n$ where $V_0= \emptyset$ and $V_{n+1}=V_n\cup P(V_n)$

Thanks

Comment: [Superstructure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superstructure.html) over any infinite set satisfies first two conditions. As for the third, it is simply a matter of unwinding how functions are represented as sets of ordered pairs, and checking that those sets belong to $V_{\omega}$ by definition.

Comment: The set $Z=\{\mathbb N,P(\mathbb N),P(P(\mathbb N)),\dots\}$ satisfies the first two conditions but not the third.

Comment: @bof - Thanks. I can see the first two. If you would, I would appreciate help as to how to approach the third condition.

Comment: Since $\mathbb N\in Z$ and $Z\notin Z,$ if you can find a function $f$ with domain $\mathbb N$ and range $Z,$  that will show that the third condition is not satisfied.

Comment: Let $Z=V_A$ where $A$ is a non-zero limit ordinal and $A$ is not a regular cardinal. (E.g. $A=\omega +\omega.$) Then (1) and (2) hold but $cf(A)=B\in V_A$ and there is a function $f:B\to A$ with $\sup \{f(x):x\in B\}=A$ so $f\not \in V_A.$

Comment: @bof I've thought for some time to come up with such a function. (No excuses for this attempt.) There are no surjective functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $P(\mathbb{N})$; can I let $f(n)=n$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$? Thanks,

Comment: If $$\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$$ and $$Z=\{\mathbb N,P(\mathbb N),P(P(\mathbb N)),\dots\}$$ then the most obvious function with domain $\mathbb N$ and range $Z$ is the function $f$ such that $f(1)=\mathbb N,\ f(2)=P(\mathbb N),\ f(3)=P(P(\mathbb N)),$ etc.

Comment: @bof Thanks you. Maybe you would please post your comment as an answer so I may accept it. With regards,

Comment: You can accept the answer posted by Athar Abdul-Quader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z = \{ \mathbb{N}, P(\mathbb{N}), P(P(\mathbb{N})), \ldots \}$. Notice that this set is countable -- you should be able to find a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $Z$ (hint: find a function $f$ so that $f(0) = \mathbb{N}, f(1) = P(\mathbb{N})$, etc.). It's not hard to see that 1 and 2 are satisfied by this $Z$, and by finding such a surjection, you can get a counterexample for 3.